# Chrome mobile error with lots of preloaded audio

Tags: javascript, html, audio, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

[Intervention] Blocked attempt to create a WebMediaPlayer as there are too many WebMediaPlayers already in existence. See crbug.com/1144736#c27

I am creating a pwa website that functions like an app more than a website. This error happens when I try to put more than 40 audio elements in my html for preloading. I'm preloading the audio because it is a bunch of small sfx that I want to play instantly instead of loading and then playing. Chrome mobile is the only browser that seems to have problems with my code. When I try to play audio from elements for which this error was thrown, the audio promise stays pending. This wasn't an issue earlier in development, and I'm not sure why it changed. Here are some relevant snippets:

```
<audio id="crowd400" preload="auto" hidden>         <source src="audio/crowd400.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="crowd450" preload="auto" hidden>         <source src="audio/crowd450.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="crowd500" preload="auto" hidden>         <source src="audio/crowd500.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="intro song" preload="auto" hidden>       <source src="audio/intro.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="outro song" preload="auto" hidden>       <source src="audio/outro.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="start game" preload="auto" hidden>       <source src="audio/soulful.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="soda" preload="auto" hidden>             <source src="audio/soda.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="tunes0" preload="auto" hidden>           <source src="audio/win.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="losers" preload="auto" hidden>           <source src="audio/trombone.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="jackpot" preload="auto" hidden>          <source src="audio/jackpot.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="winners" preload="auto" hidden>          <source src="audio/loud.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="winner" preload="auto" hidden>           <source src="audio/normal.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="drumroll" preload="auto" hidden>         <source src="audio/drumroll.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="gargling" preload="auto" hidden>         <source src="audio/gargling.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="car" preload="auto" hidden>              <source src="audio/car.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="hiss0" preload="auto" hidden>            <source src="audio/hiss0.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="hiss1" preload="auto" hidden>            <source src="audio/hiss1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="fart0" preload="auto" hidden>            <source src="audio/fart0.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="fart1" preload="auto" hidden>            <source src="audio/fart1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="fart2" preload="auto" hidden>            <source src="audio/fart2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="fart3" preload="auto" hidden>            <source src="audio/fart3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="fart4" preload="auto" hidden>            <source src="audio/fart4.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="fart5" preload="auto" hidden>            <source src="audio/fart5.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="fart6" preload="auto" hidden>            <source src="audio/fart6.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="fart7" preload="auto" hidden>            <source src="audio/fart7.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="fart8" preload="auto" hidden>            <source src="audio/fart8.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="fart9" preload="auto" hidden>            <source src="audio/fart9.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="fart10" preload="auto" hidden>           <source src="audio/fart10.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="fart11" preload="auto" hidden>           <source src="audio/fart11.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="fart12" preload="auto" hidden>           <source src="audio/fart12.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="fart13" preload="auto" hidden>           <source src="audio/fart13.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="fart14" preload="auto" hidden>           <source src="audio/fart14.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="fart15" preload="auto" hidden>           <source src="audio/fart15.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="fart16" preload="auto" hidden>           <source src="audio/fart16.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="fart17" preload="auto" hidden>           <source src="audio/fart17.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="fart18" preload="auto" hidden>           <source src="audio/fart18.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="fart19" preload="auto" hidden>           <source src="audio/fart19.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="fart20" preload="auto" hidden>           <source src="audio/fart20.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="fart21" preload="auto" hidden>           <source src="audio/fart21.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="fart22" preload="auto" hidden>           <source src="audio/fart22.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="Puppy Crying" preload="auto" hidden>     <source src="audio/puppy.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="Kitten Meow" preload="auto" hidden>      <source src="audio/kitten.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="Male Scream No 1" preload="auto" hidden> <source src="audio/no1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="Male Scream No 2" preload="auto" hidden> <source src="audio/no2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="Evil Clown Laugh" preload="auto" hidden> <source src="audio/clown.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="Bassoon" preload="auto" hidden>          <source src="audio/bassoon.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="Dragon" preload="auto" hidden>           <source src="audio/dragon.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="Burp" preload="auto" hidden>             <source src="audio/burp.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="Comedy Wah Wah 1" preload="auto" hidden> <source src="audio/comedy1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="Comedy Wah Wah 2" preload="auto" hidden> <source src="audio/comedy2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="Heartbeat" preload="auto" hidden>        <source src="audio/heartbeat.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="Clock" preload="auto" hidden>            <source src="audio/clock.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="Deep Evil Hover 1" preload="auto" hidden><source src="audio/deep1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="Deep Evil Hover 2" preload="auto" hidden><source src="audio/deep2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="Deep Evil Hover 3" preload="auto" hidden><source src="audio/deep3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="Creepy Cat 1" preload="auto" hidden>     <source src="audio/creepy1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="Creepy Cat 2" preload="auto" hidden>     <source src="audio/creepy2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="snacks0" preload="auto" hidden>          <source src="audio/chips0.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="snacks1" preload="auto" hidden>          <source src="audio/chips1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="snacks2" preload="auto" hidden>          <source src="audio/chips2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="snacks3" preload="auto" hidden>          <source src="audio/chips3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="snacks4" preload="auto" hidden>          <source src="audio/chips4.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="snacks5" preload="auto" hidden>          <source src="audio/chips5.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="paper0" preload="auto" hidden>           <source src="audio/paper0.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="paper1" preload="auto" hidden>           <source src="audio/paper1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="paper2" preload="auto" hidden>           <source src="audio/paper2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="paper3" preload="auto" hidden>           <source src="audio/paper3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="paper4" preload="auto" hidden>           <source src="audio/paper4.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="paper5" preload="auto" hidden>           <source src="audio/paper5.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="whistle0" preload="auto" hidden>         <source src="audio/whistle0.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="whistle1" preload="auto" hidden>         <source src="audio/whistle1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="whistle2" preload="auto" hidden>         <source src="audio/whistle2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="whistle3" preload="auto" hidden>         <source src="audio/whistle3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="whistle4" preload="auto" hidden>         <source src="audio/whistle4.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="whistle5" preload="auto" hidden>         <source src="audio/whistle5.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="whistle6" preload="auto" hidden>         <source src="audio/whistle6.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="ohyeah0" preload="auto" hidden>          <source src="audio/ohyeah0.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="ohyeah1" preload="auto" hidden>          <source src="audio/ohyeah1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="ohyeah2" preload="auto" hidden>          <source src="audio/ohyeah2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

```js
function playAudio(audioID) {
  if(muted) return;
  if(currentAudio)
    stopAudio();
    currentAudio = document.getElementById(audioID);
    currentAudio.play()
    /*.catch((error) => { console.log(audioID + ": " + currentAudio +
      " | " + currentAudio.childNodes[0].src + ", " + error) })*/;
  return currentAudio;
}
```

I've tried marking the audio elements as hidden, but it doesn't help. Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome mobile v92 only allows you to have 40 preloaded audios.